# Why does executing Spark application fail in IntelliJ IDEA with "NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/mllib/regression/LabeledPoint"?

Tags: scala, maven, apache-spark, intellij-idea, apache-spark-mllib

I've been writing a simple code using Spark MLlib and scala.
But, when I ran the code, I got the error **"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/mllib/regression/LabeledPoint"**
. What causes this error?

And the IDE tool (IntelliJ) told me "LinearRegressionWithSGD is deprecated"
I installed the spark version of 2.2.0 and the scala version of 2.11.
What am I supposed to do? if I want to use the "LinearRegressionWithSGD".

Please help me with this.

The code is as follows:

```
import org.apache.spark.{SparkContext, SparkConf}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LinearRegressionWithSGD
import org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vectors

import java.io.StringWriter
import au.com.bytecode.opencsv.CSVWriter
import scala.collection.JavaConversions._
import java.io.FileWriter
import java.io.BufferedWriter

import java.io.File

// feature vector
var _00h = Array(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)

object CacheAlgoApp {
  def main(args: Array[String]) : Unit = {

      // Load and parse the data
      var data = sc.textFile("test.log")
      var operationData = data.filter(line => line.contains("operations"))

      val adjustTime = 6

      var parsedData = operationData.map { line =>
        var parts = line.split(' ')
        LabeledPoint(parts(adjustTime+0).toDouble, Vectors.dense(_00h.take(24).map(_.toDouble)))
      }

      // Build linear regression model
      var regression = new LinearRegressionWithSGD().setIntercept(false)
      regression.optimizer.setNumIterations(200)
      regression.optimizer.setStepSize(1) //0.0, 0.20999999999999963, 0.03999999999999999
      var model00 = regression.run(parsedData)

    }    
}
```

And the pom.xml is as follows. Could It be the problem of the dependency?

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-core_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-mllib -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.spark</groupId>
        <artifactId>spark-mllib_2.11</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: How do you _"But, when I ran the code"_? How do you build the executable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** Remove `provided` scope for `spark-mllib_2.11` dependency and start over.

The reason for the exception is that you ran the code without Spark MLlib on the application's classpath.

However you ran the code the class uses Spark MLlib's `LinearRegressionWithSGD` and so requires the class to be available on CLASSPATH.

Executing Spark code using Intellij IDEA can *sometimes* be tricky to get right, but *usually* just works. If it does not, it's highly advised to use the recommended way of submitting a Spark application (of any kind with or without Spark MLlib) using `spark-submit` as described in the Spark official documentation's [Submitting Applications](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html):

> The `spark-submit` script in Spark’s bin directory is used to launch applications on a cluster.

Just skip *"on a cluster"* part as that's of no help here (and actually incorrect).

`spark-mllib_2.11` dependency that represents Spark MLlib at code level is in `provided` scope and hence unavailable on your Spark application's CLASSPATH. Remove `provided` scope and start over. It's supposed to work fine.